# Stripping unicode characters out of slug

Tags: slug

I am trying to strip the following characters out of slugs: ṁ, ṭ, ḍ, ṇ, ṅ, ñ, ḷ, ṃ.

I found this code [here](https://tommcfarlin.com/remove-special-characters-from-permalinks/) (note: I have removed `public` in order to get it to work)

```
add_action('wp_insert_post_data', __NAMESPACE__ . 'processPermalink');
/**
 * Processes the permalink so we can remove any characters that may cause a problem when communicating
 * with the API.
 *
 * @param  array $data The array of information about the post.
 * @return array $data The data without the malformed information in the post name for the URL.
 */
function processPermalink($data)
{
    if (!in_array($data['post_status'], array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft'))) {
        $data['post_name'] =
            preg_replace(
                '/(%ef%b8%8f|™|®|©|&trade;|&reg;|&copy;|&#8482;|&#174;|&#169;)/',
                '',
                $data['post_name']
            );
    }
    return $data;
}
```

I have tried replacing the `preg_replace` in these three ways, but none of them work (the original code does what it shoudl):

```
'/(&#8424;&#8424;&#8424;&#7745;|&#7789;|&#7693;|&#7751;|&#7749;|&#241;|&#7735;|&#7747;)/'
```

```
'/(&#x1E41;|&#x1E6D;|&#x1E0D;|&#x1E47;|&#x1E45;|&ntilde;|&#x1E37;|&#x1E43;)/'
```

```
'/(ṁ|ṭ|ḍ|ṇ|ṅ|ñ|ḷ|ṃ)/'
```

None of them successfully strip out the characters.

EDIT: I don't actually have to accomplish my goal using the above code. I'd be happy to do it some other way, including substituting the bad characters with their non-accented versions.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at how the inbuilt function `remove_accents()` does it [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_accents/) - you may need to adjust the initial `preg_match()` regex if those characters are in a different range.

Comment: Hmm. Do you have any idea why the main code I posted above would work for characters like ™, ®, and © but not the ones I am trying to do? Are you saying it's because of the range of those characters? I'm a bit out of my depth with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'/(ṁ|ṭ|ḍ|ṇ|ṅ|ñ|ḷ|ṃ)/'` is a valid regex to process what you want.

```php
$string = '/(ṁ|ṭ|ḍ|ṇ|ṅ|ñ|ḷ|ṃ)/ is my regex and my chosen string is: ṁ, ṭ, ḍ, ṇ, ṅ, ñ, ḷ, ṃ';


echo preg_replace(
    '/(ṁ|ṭ|ḍ|ṇ|ṅ|ñ|ḷ|ṃ)/',
    '',
    $string,
);

// Returns '/(|||||||)/ is my regex and my chosen string is: , , , , , , , '
```

**EDIT**: So the issue is that the slug had already been `urlencode`d at this point.

Try this

```php
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'wpse_406105_process_permalink', 10, 1 );
/**
 * Processes the permalink so we can remove any characters that may cause a problem when communicating
 * with the API.
 *
 * @param  array $data The array of information about the post.
 * @return array $data The data without the malformed information in the post name for the URL.
 */
function wpse_406105_process_permalink( $data ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $data['post_status'], array( 'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft' ) ) ) {
        $data['post_name'] =
            preg_replace(
                '/(%E1%B9%81|%E1%B9%AD|%E1%B8%8D|%E1%B9%87|%E1%B9%85|%C3%B1|%E1%B8%B7|%E1%B9%83)/i',

                '',
                $data['post_name']
            );
    }
    return $data;
}
```

You don't want a namespace there, you have converted it to make it a procedural function. It's a good idea to make procedural functions fairly uniquely named to avoid conflicts so I have also changed the function from `processPermalink()`.

It's also worth noting that these do not function until you have published the post - drafts, auto drafts and pending posts are skipped.

Comment: Hi there - sorry I re read this and saw in the original code that the original hook was actually an action. And you don't ask to pass any parameters - change line 1 to what it is now. `add_filter` and with priority and no of params after ( `, 10, 1 );`)

Comment: I would say it's unlikely to affect the regex - have you tried running the test code I posted at the top? If possible in the same environment as this isn't working? You could also try outputting the string before it's run through the regex to double check the string we're trying to replace for any inconsistencies. I'll also add this into a test env to double check - hopefully today :-)

Comment: One or both of us was being silly - the slug is already run through `urlencode` at this point - wrong needle, right haystack.